# Compare only last column in a file

Tags: c#

I have a file, like:

```
outlook temperature Humidity  Windy  PlayTennis

sunny      hot        high     false   N

sunny      hot        high     true    N

overcast   hot        high     false   P

sunny      hot        high     false   P
```

I basically want to compare the first and last column. Want sunny-n then occur-no ++ and sunny-P occur_yes++

I wrote the code as

I have taken the while loop which reads every row, the problem i am getting is, every time, it goes in the loop for `occur_yes+`+ as the value of check becomes the last column value, but I want that if the last column is P then it should go in `occur_yes` else it should go in `occur_No`.

Hope I am clear.

I am a freshiee..pls help me out

Answer (score 0):

This code should do what you are looking for:

```
int occur_yes = 0;
int occur_no  = 0;
// open file
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader("inputFile.txt"))
{
    // read lines one at a time
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // split the line
        string[] cols = line.Split('\t');
        if (cols[0] == "sunny")
        {
            // check last column only if the first one is "sunny"
            if (cols[4] == "N")
                occur_no++;
            else if (cols[4] == "P")
                occur_yes++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to keep thing static..
so here, in place of N and P, what should come ??

if (cols[4] == "N") ,, else if (cols[4] == "P")

Comment: What do you need to not be static? 4 or P|N?

Comment: Nothing..i made 4 dynamic..
pt = allcolumn1[read_count - 1].ToString();
check = pt;
This check gives me, N or P
But for every line, it goes in the first loop and makes occur_yes ++, it does not go into the other loop.
Because, every time, it takes the value of check and compares with the allcolumn1[lastcol].ToString() which gives last column value, but though it is N or P it does not go in the 2nd loop

Comment: @user2163048 I'm sorry but I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do. Do you want to compare the value of the last col for the line `n` with the one of the line `n-1`?